# Is it possible to rebase-squash only certain commits on a feature branch

Tags: git, rebase

I've created a feature branch, and while I've been working on it, I've been merging from the master branch work from other people.

Now my feature branch is complete and I'd like to rebase all my changes into a clean single commit, however, my commits are not all sequential as I've merged commits from the master branch during that time.

Is it possible to somehow ignore their commits as I'm changing my commits from 'pick' to 'squash'.

I tried deleting them from the list but they still were squashed or merged and I don't know if I should submit my pull request like this as it might have squashed other people's work giving me the credit.

Comment: please have a look at `git rebase --interactive`

Comment: that's what I'm using git rebase -i, I get the list of commits, I suppose those I leave under 'pick' remain unsquashed.

Comment: Can you first rebase to linearize the history, then squash?

Answer (score 0):

One possibility is `reset --soft`:

```
git checkout yourbranch
git merge origin/master # make sure all changes of master are included
git reset --soft origin/master
git commit -m 'Your squashed commit message comes here'
```

This will create a single new commit on master containing your latest snapshot, containing all changes from your branch and from master. The difference against master will be only your changes.